# WPF MVVM Report a progress from another class?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm developing an app in C# WPF, the requirement is to use the MVVM pattern, but I'm struggling to find information on how to report progress to a progress bar which the progress value comes from another class, I'll try to explain myself better with code.

**MainWindowVieModel.cs**

```
//...
//...
public void StartSearch(object obj)
{
  search.SearchByName(string a); //CALL TO THE METHOD IN THE SEARCH CLASS
}
//...
//...
```

**Search.cs**

```
public string SearchByName(string searchString){
//..
//..
    for (int i = 0;i <x;i++)
    {
        //HERE I NEED TO REPORT I AS PROGRESS VALUE
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs** where i bind the MainWindowViewModel as DataContext.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

Is that even possible to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: expose an event in the Search class, then fire it from within the SearchByName loop. The listener (it is up to you) should subscribe that event, then process something graphic. Consider also the event unsubscription, if necessary.

Comment: @MarioVernari con you provide a basic example for better understanding?

Comment: the answer proposed is exactly what I mean.

Comment: You could also add an IProgress<int> parameter to the SearchByName method. For me, this is easier to use and re-use than the combination of a method and an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible. What you need to do is set up an event in your `Search` class:

```
public event Action<int> ProgressChanged;
```

Then setup the event to be raised inside your loop:

```
public string SearchByName(string searchString){
    for (int i = 0; I < x; i++)
    {
        //...
        ProgressChanged?.Invoke(i);
    }
}
```

Then subscribe to that event in your `MainWindowVieModel`. A good place to do this is your constructor:

```
public class MainWindowVieModel()
{
    Search.ProgressChanged += UpdateValueInProgressBar(i);
}
```

Lastly, you'll have to make your `StartSearch` method `async` for it not to freeze your UI:

```
public async void StartSearch(object obj)
{
  await Task.Run(() => search.SearchByName(string a);
}
```

Note that you don't really need the `UpdateValueInProgressBar()`, I just leave it like that for you to decide how the binding to the XAML is done in your own class.

Should you have any questions, please do ask! I hope this helps you.

Edit: Please do note that as @Mario Vernari commented, unsubscribing from the event is a good idea to prevent memory leaks. You'll have to decide where to do this in your application. A possible solution could be by doing it in the method itself:

```
public async void StartSearch(object obj)
{
  Search.ProgressChanged += UpdateValueInProgressBar();
  await Task.Run(() => search.SearchByName(string a);
  Search.ProgressChanged -= UpdateValueInProgressBar();
}
```

Edit: You requested an example of the `UpdateValueInProgressBar` method. I will assume that your `MainWindowVieModel` exposes a `Progress` and a `Max` property to your view:

```
public class MainWindowVieModel
{
        private int _Progress;
        public int Progress
        {
            get => _Progress;
            set { _Progress = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
        }
}
```

And you bind to that property in your XAML:

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress}" />
```

This is, of course, just an example. In your application, you'll also need a way to know what is the maximum value of `i` you're expecting (here is set to 100).
These answers are really meant to give you a little direction. It's up to you to work around your specific scenario.

Comment: upvoted, because that's also in my mind. However, you should complete the code with an unsubscription of the event. We don't know how the original code is, and keeping stick the event subscribed could lead to memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, good point. Would you then subscribe to it before calling `await Task.Run(() => search.SearchByName(string a);` and then unsubscribe right after?

Comment: I think is up to the authod decide where to unsubscribe, because it depends on the original code. Just add the snippet, and highlight the fact that the unsubscription is important.

Comment: If you're using an event it should really be a weak event unless Search.cs is instantiated by mainwindowviewmodel. In which case, an event is not necessary.

Comment: @yosef-bernal thanks for the replay con youplease add the declaration of the method UpdateValueInProgressBar please?

Comment: I will edit shortly with an example. But do know that this depends on how view model and view are structured.

Comment: Is the search class specific to mainwindowviewmodel, or is it used elsewhere? Does it use complex code dependent on multiple sources or are these from mainwindowviewmodel?

Comment: furthermore I can't see i from mainviewmodel at Search.ProgressChanged += UpdateValueInProgressBar(i);

Comment: @Andy Search class is in another cs file

Comment: @FabioEnne can you indicate if this answered your question? if not what is missing? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is insufficient information as the question stands to know what is the "best" solution for this.

An event means a strong reference which is usually considered a bad idea because of the risk of memory leaks.
Weak events are designed to avoid that but aren't as simple.

Here are some others:

Mvvmlight messenger

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26070.communicating-between-classes.aspx or prism event aggregator. Both use weak events. Prism involves passing a reference to a bridging object.

Bind value

You can either expose a SearchVM instance as a property in mainviewmodel or a property in mainwindowviewmodel and bind that to Value on the progressbar. Set that in SearchVM either directly or indirectly passing an action into search from searchvm.  Maybe it's a bit pointless having a separate search class. We don't know.

Custom Routed event

Depending on where search is invoked from, there might be some usercontrol maybe. This can raise a routed event and the parent of this progressbar can listen to this. Driving the routed event would be a dependency property of the usercontrol. We don't know if being encapsulated and re-usable is worth while though.

Pass reference via Dependency injection

This is a variation of binding.

A property of mainwindowviewmodel could be progressVM.cs. This could be a singleton provioded via DI. There is likely only one progress to show at any given point in time.  Bind value of the progressbar to property of progressvm. Pass progressvm into search via DI. Set the value property in search.cs.